# A problem with the number of sections

Tags: sectioning, errors

How to change number format of section from number 0.1 to number 1, picture below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[a6paper, top=15mm, left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=10mm,foot=5mm,marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
%showframe
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}  %\toprule
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{wasysym} % symbols
\usepackage{amssymb} % symbols
%\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}


\newcommand*{\knihaB}{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaA}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaC}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaM}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihaEa}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaEb}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihacc}{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaaa}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihabb}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

\section{{\knihaEa text }} 

text    text    text    text    text    text    


\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your image link does not work (for me), but you're using `book` and have no top chapter above `\section`, so what do you expect `\thesection` should produce? It is usually defined (effectively) as `\thechapter.\arabic{section}`. None of the packages you are using changes this. So use `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` if this is what you want to have.

Comment: And don't load `hyperref` in the middle of the bunch of packages, put it at the end of the preamble

Comment: Don't load packages multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm posting this answer mainly so that the query may be treated as having been answered officially.)

- To change the appearance of the section number, modify the macro `\thesection`. Given your stated objective, you should run

  ```
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
  ```
- Do take some time to simplify and de-cruft the preamble of your document. At the moment, several packages are loaded more than once, while others needn't be loaded explicitly. E.g., the `rotating` package loads the `graphicx` package automatically -- no need to load `graphicx` separately. In the code below, I've also attempted to provide some structure and sequencing to the way the packages are loaded.
- With very few exceptions, the `hyperref` package should be loaded *last* in the preamble. See the posting [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5001) for some of these exceptions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a6paper]{book}

%% basic setup and layout
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=slovak,english]{babel}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=15mm, bottom=10mm, hmargin=10mm, 
        foot=5mm, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}

%% various symbols
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{wasysym} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{marvosym}

%% advanced tabular layouts
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% other packages
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%% various font-related macros
\newcommand*{\knihaB}{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaA}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaC}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaM}{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihaEa}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaEb}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}

\newcommand*{\knihacc}{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihaaa}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}
\newcommand*{\knihabb}{\fontfamily{ccr}\selectfont}

%% hyperlinking -- load this package *last*
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% change the "look" of printed section-level numbers
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\-=12
\sloppy

\section{\knihaEa text }

text    text    text    text    text    text    
\end{document}
```